# How to toggle the appearance of content on clicking on a paragraph jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want some html content to appear when clicking on the text, such as a button or an input, and on second click, its disappear

```
<p class="test">test</p>
<script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-pumBsjNRGGqkPzKHndZMaAG+bir374sORyzM3uulLV14lN5LyykqNk8eEeUlUkB3U0M4FApyaHraT65ihJhDpQ=="
    crossorigin="anonymous"
    referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
></script>
<script>
var toggle = 0;

$( "p" ).click(function() {
    var htmlorig = $( this ).html();
    if (toggle != 1) {
        var toggle = 1;
        $( this ).html( htmlorig + '<button>sds</button>' );
      } else {
        var toggle = 0;
        $( this ).html( htmlorig );
      }
});
</script>
```

**Here is codepen https://codepen.io/pire-code/pen/QWZyVZE**

I tried this, didn't work.
I am aware that I can use another cdn.
Help, please.

Comment: `<p>Text</p><button>Foo</button>`/`button { display: none; }`/`$('p').click(() => $('button').toggle());`. See [`jQuery.toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the original HTML and the toggle variable inside a closure with `.each`.

```js
$('p').each(function() {
  const $this = $(this);
  const htmlOrig = $this.html();
  let toggle = 1;
  $this.click(function(e) {
    $this.html(toggle ? htmlOrig + ' <button>sds</button>' : htmlOrig);
    toggle ^= 1;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="test">test</p>
```